# WPF: Tooltip on the fill of a Path

Tags: wpf, path, tooltip

I want to assign a tooltip to a System.Windows.Shape.Path.

While the tooltip pops up when I touch the outline of the path I get no tooltip when I am inside the filled part of the path.

Can I change this behavior in some way?
My only idea was to add the path to an additional control like a canvas and assign the tooltip to the canvas. But that seems to be a lot of work.

Is there any other way?

EDIT: The path is and should be filled. The tooltip should popup on the path outline and on the filled area inside.

Comment: The sample I gave will work for a path using the fill property. Can you expand upon the shape of the path and what is currently filling it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have not set the Fill property, the behavior you have is expected. Consider setting the Fill property to Transparent if you simply want an "outline" Path.

```
<Path Fill="Transparent" 
      ToolTip="My Tooltip" 
      Data="..." Stroke="..." StrokeThickness="..."  />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the path dynamically, you can set like this:

```
Path p = new Path();
........
.......
p.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
p.SetValue(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, "Tooltip is here");
```

Comment: Above code will work if you have Fill the path otherwise ,I do not think it will work