# WPF add custom tooltip for a Path

Tags: wpf, path, tooltip, shapes

I am building dynamically more paths in a canvas, and i want to add a tooltip with more details about the path shape. But it looks like the tolltip appears only when i hover the path points. I want it to appear also when i hover the filled area or the contour of it.

```
                PolyLineSegment polySeg = new PolyLineSegment(new Point[] { new Point(triangleX - 8, triangleY - 20), new Point(triangleX + 8, triangleY - 20) }, true);
                PathFigure pathFig = new PathFigure(new Point(triangleX, triangleY), new PathSegment[] { polySeg }, true);
                PathGeometry pathGeo = new PathGeometry(new PathFigure[] { pathFig });
                pathGeo.Transform = new RotateTransform(angleOfTheTriangleInGrades, triangleX, triangleY);

                Path path = new Path();
                path.Data = pathGeo;
                path.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;


                var sp = new StackPanel();
                sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "aaa"
                });

                sp.Children.Add(new Button
                {
                    Height = 20,
                    Width = 100,
                    Content = "bbbaaa"
                });

                path.ToolTip = sp;

                pathList.Add(path);
```

Comment: Have you tried out any of the solutions suggested as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189468/wpf-tooltip-on-the-fill-of-a-path)?

Comment: I saw that those answers are not marked as a valid answer. But it seams like the second one is working in my case (cause i will always have the path filled.

Comment: But in some cases i have another canvas on top of it. And in this case even if the canvas from top is transparent, the tooltip not appear anymore. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem? To persist the hover.

Comment: @XmaWaZZ set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the Canvas that appears on top.

Comment: It would work but not in my case cause i have 2 canvas with the same dimension. These 2 canvas are overlapping, but each one will contains a different path. Just imagine a square split in 2 paths. So if i will set this property to the canvas on the top, i will not have tooltip for that path. But i will create another ticket for it because it's a different problem. Thanks for your help